# Lock overlay on Custom Geoprocessing Tools

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, arctoolbox

How do you get rid of the "lock" icon overlay on a custom geoprocessing tool in ArcToolbox?

This seems to appear even with the [ESRI Sample Projects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000002r6000000.htm).

Comment: This is probably a new thing in ArcGIS 10, since I did never get any overlays on my custom tools in ArcGIS 9.3.

Comment: @petr: Yeah - the custom tools always look like they're not licensed, even if IsLicensed() returns true... not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Interesting... I'll try to port some of my tools to ArcGIS 10 and see what is does.

Comment: With models I was able to edit models - validate - save and the icon disappeared.

Comment: @Jakub: I'm doing code-based (COM API) IGPFunction tools - don't think there is a corresponding function for that, though...

Comment: @Reed: strangely enough, my tool does not exhibit this behavior. I was able to simulate it only by returning false from IsLicensed. Are you able to execute the tool or do you get the "not licensed" message?

Comment: @petr: I can execute it fine.  I even built the sample area tool (linked above), and get the same issue there.

Comment: Even though I have my own set of base classes (base factory class, base function class) to ease the repeated implementation of name-related methods, parameter validation, exception handling and such, there are very little conceptual differences to the ESRI-provided sample. The only difference I spotted is the implementation of GetFunctionNames, where ESRI calls (in their CreateGPFunctionNames method) "functionName.MinimumProduct = esriProductCode.esriProductCodeProfessional", whereas I do not. I did try to use this and recreated the TBX file. The locked overlay appeared shortly in ArcCatalog,

Comment: and then disappeared. In your case the overlays stays there, I guess, but for the moment it might be your best bet to look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to the ESRI-provided sample, **do not set** [IGPFunctionName.MinimumProduct](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/002n/002n00000290000000.htm) when implementing [IGPFunctionFactory.GetFunctionNames](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/002n/002n0000028s000000.htm) and [IGPFunctionFactory.GetFunctionName](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/002n/002n0000028r000000.htm) (or any other IGPFunctionName related methods).

EDIT: You can of course set the property to the appropriate level. The ESRI sample uses the (highest) esriProductCode.esriProductCodeProfessional level (ArcInfo) which, in majority of cases, is not what you want.

Comment: That was it.  I pull that out, and it goes away... Turns out from here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Get_ArcGIS_License_Name_Snippet/004900000066000000/    Professional is ArcInfo, so this makes sense...

Comment: That clarifies it. I edited the answer to reflect this information.