# How do I get around license error when creating custom tool?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, .net

I created a custom geoprocessing function tool according to this link . . http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Building_a_custom_geoprocessing_function_tool/00010000049w000000/

I went through the following instructions in order to create a custom tool in a toolbox, but got the error "You do not have the necessary license to execute the selected tool" when attempting to run the custom tool . . .

1) Register the DLL (in the Debug folder) with ESRIRegAsm utility. ESRIRegAsm.exe is located at, ~:\Program Files\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin folder. Use this example . . . Do the following to register the assembly:
               Desktop—ESRIRegAsm /p:desktop "C:\Test\MyAssembly.dll"

```
           Engine—ESRIRegAsm /p:engine "C:\Test\MyAssembly.dll"
```

2) Create a custom toolbox in a folder or a geodatabase. 
ArcGIS for Desktop users have the option to add the tool to a custom toolbox manually in ArcCatalog, ArcMap, or ArcGlobe. Right-click a custom toolbox, choose Add, click Tool, expand my function factory, select my tool, and click OK. The tool is added to the custom toolbox.

Comment: What are you returning for `IGPFunction.IsLicensed` ?

Comment: What license level are you running at? different ArcObjects methods are available depending on license level. Also, if you're not doing complex analysis, you may be better served with a Python tool to start, the debugging cycle is much simpler

Comment: Besides `IGPFunction.IsLicensed()`, also check [what you return from IGPFunctionName.MinimumProduct](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/3119/434).

Comment: The IsLicensed function returned "false".  I'm not sure where you're getting MinimumProduct from.

Comment: In the IsLicensed function, the licName variable contains "ArcGIS Engine". Why do I need an "Advanced" license?